# WPF Custom control , switch templated based on a column

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm building a custom user control that based on a bool property should show a template or another based on this property... I don't know how to switch....

Here's some code

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();


        rapportoSeachViewModel = DataContext as RapportoSearchViewModel;

        tbRapporto = base.Template.FindName("PART_SearchTextBox", this) as TextBox;

        if (tbRapporto != null)
        {
            tbRapporto.KeyDown += tbRapporto_KeyDown;
        }

        searchButton = base.Template.FindName("PART_SearchButton", this) as Button;

        if (searchButton != null)
        {
            searchButton.Click += searchButton_Click;
        }
    }
```

and here's my template when the property is set to true

How do I define another template on my resource dictionary and how I switch it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataTemplateSelector to achieve your requirement.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank kumar, but this datatemplate selector must be defined in my usercontrol?